# Regarding Paypal - 2016 merchant security upgrades

Tags: php, magento, ssl, paypal, verisign

We are having the website (www.kalakendra.com) on magento v1.9.2.1 which hosted on the GoDaddy cloud server. We are using the paypal express checkout with IPN service. We have received an email from paypal concerning to upgrade the paypal ssl certificate security measures.

I have gone through various forums and stackoverflow questions as well. But still i have some doubt on the impact of paypal security upgrades if we fails to do it.

Our Server Configurations are

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
Ubuntu V14.04
MySql v5.0.11
Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) 
OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.5.34 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

my doubts are,

1. Even though we don't have any SSL certificate but have the latest upgraded cloud server with openssl v1.0.2. So whether we should implement the SSL Certificate installation or no need of that?
2. Shall we can update the SHA-1 to SHA-2 and also VeriSign G2 Root Certificate  to VeriSign G5 Root Certificate without having SSL certificate?

Sorry for my poor english.

Thanks.

Comment: https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/ *If you are unsure if you fall into one of these categories, please contact the company / developer who assisted with your original integration. Typically these integrations may come through a 3rd party cart system (e.g. Zen Cart), hosting company (e.g. **GoDaddy**), or individual developer*

Answer (score 1):

Now, PayPal needs TLS 1.2 instead of 1.0 so please check in your server configuration through PHP info file. If you have TLS 1.0 version then ask your server support to upgrade it into TLS 1.2.

Comment: I have checked with the phpinfo file and it shows currently the server in TLS V1.2.